# Access fbs resource files in non-GUI code

Tags: python, pyqt5, fbs

Using [fbs](https://build-system.fman.io/) to package a PyQt5 app, what could be the cleanest way to access resource files from non-GUI code?

In the example below, I made a simple PyQt5 app with one window containing one button. The button triggers a function that will read a `.json` resource file and print its attribute `message` in the console. The function `print_data()` defined in *logic.py* should also work without the GUI app, for example to be used by other python scripts. Therefore, it cannot be move as a method of the MainWindow class.

It is easy and handy to use the application context's `get_resource()` method to get the path to *mainwindow.ui*. Unfortunately, it cannot be used by `print_data()` to get the path to *static_data.json* as the function has no access to the application context.

What would be the best solution?

- Use fbs's resources system only for gui-related resource files and keep *static_data.json* with the python files?
- Try to access the application context outside of the MainWindow class?
- Use another python resources library such as **pkg_resources** to handle non gui-related resource files?
- Use another tool such as **cx_freeze** to package the app?

---

Directory structure:

```
|-- src
|  |-- main
|  |  |-- python
|  |  |  |-- main.py
|  |  |  |-- gui.py
|  |  |  |-- logic.py
|  |  |-- resources
|  |  |  |-- base
|  |  |  |  |-- mainwindow.ui
|  |  |  |  |-- static_data.json
```

Content of `main.py`:

```
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
import sys
from gui import MainWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appctxt = ApplicationContext()
    window = MainWindow(appctxt)
    window.show()
    exit_code = appctxt.app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Content of `gui.py`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic

from logic import print_data


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, context):
        super().__init__()

        # Loading the .ui file from the resources
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(context.get_resource("mainwindow.ui"), self)

        # Binding the button to the print_data function defined in logic.py
        self.main_button.clicked.connect(print_data)
```

Content of `logic.py`:

```
import json


def print_data():

    # Getting the resource data filepath
    filepath = "../resources/base/static_data.json"

    # Processing the resource file
    with open(filepath) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        print(data["message"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
python
├── base.py
├── gui.py
├── logic.py
└── main.py
```

One possible solution is to create the context in a file where everyone can access that variable:

**base.py**

```py
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext

context = ApplicationContext()
```

Then it is used in the other classes:

**gui.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic

from base import context

from logic import print_data


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Loading the .ui file from the resources
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(context.get_resource("mainwindow.ui"), self)

        # Binding the button to the print_data function defined in logic.py
        self.main_button.clicked.connect(print_data)
```

**logic.py**

```py
import json

from base import context


def print_data():
    # Getting the resource data filepath
    filepath = context.get_resource("static_data.json")

    # Processing the resource file
    with open(filepath) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        print(data["message"])
```

**main.py**

```py
import sys

from base import context
from gui import MainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(250, 150)
    window.show()
    exit_code = context.app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```